# After compiling a program in Qt with a icon, the icon which is on taskbar looks worst

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

I have made a GUI version of one of my program with icon, my problem is when my program starts then the icon in task bar looks worst and pixelated whereas if I compile a non-GUI version of the same program with Code blocks and same icon then the icon displays completely fine and crisp. What could be the problem in case of Qt? I even tried a big 120x120 icon also but still it is very pixelated and no improvement. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with "if I compile a non-GUI version of the same program with Code blocks"? Code blocks is only the IDE (which is very outdated by the way), not a compiler and nothing which should change the behavior of your application... And you can't have system tray icons in a non-GUI Qt application. How do you set the tray icon?

Comment: I am not talking about tray icon, the icon on taskbar, the main taskbar not system tray, For non-GUI thing, I meant to say a simple console application with icon set using resources.rc, I did same ith Qt but icon is very blurry and pixelated

Comment: Does your project (.pro) file have an RC_FILE entry pointing to resources.rc?

Comment: Are you setting stylesheet via code/IDE in your GUI version??

Comment: Yes I have RC file ofcourse and I don't have icon set using stylesheet method, how to do that?

Comment: What version of Qt are you using and what version of Windows are you using? I'm assuming it's Windows since you said taskbar. I've noticed that low resolution icons can cause pixelation if they are upscaled by Qt in the taskbar in Windows 8 and possibly other versions of Windows. Maybe this is the case?